# Is this weaker form of Chowla's conjecture potentially interesting?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I began to read a post on Terry Tao's blog dealing with Chowla's conjecture, and doing so I came to think about a weaker form thereof.
So for a given positive integer $m$, let $S_{m}(x)$ denote the following sum: $$\sum_{n\leqslant x}\prod_{d\mid m}\mu(n+d)$$.

Would it be interesting to (try to) establish that $S_{m}(x)=o(x)$ taking advantage of the fact that the set of positive divisors of $m$ is invariant under the action of the map $d\mapsto\frac{m}{d}$? If yes, which consequences of arithmetic interest could be obtained?

Edit: this "weaker" form of Chowla's conjecture may actually be equivalent thereto, since letting $m=k!$ or $m=lcm(1, 2,\cdots,k)$ may imply that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n\leqslant x}\prod_{i=1}^{k}\mu(n+i)=o(x)}$.

Comment: For which m is the summand nonzero?  Gerhard "Maybe It Is Too Weak" Paseman, 2019.11.13.

Comment: I think the issue you point out is also present in the original Chowla conjecture, no?

Comment: The version I saw has exponents, some of which can be zero. Other versions have a sparse subset of  offsets from 1 through m. Not only do you need to worry about mod 4 considerations, but also mod 9, etc. Gerhard "Hey Man! Don't Be Square!" Paseman, 2019.11.13.

Comment: So squarefree values of $m$ should limit those problems.